# Can't log in - Firebase + React Native

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am using a case when statement to recognise the toggling of user's loggedIn state and display content accordingly. But this doesn't seem to work.

loggedIn: True - should give me the content I want to display to logged in users
loggedIn: False - should show the log-in form
default:  buffer spinner

I currently start with **loggedIn: null**; in this state I only see the spinner. If I use **loggedIn: false** then I can see the form but attempt to log in stops at the spinner.

When I manually set the state to 'true' or 'false' then I am able to get the desired output through case when statement.

Here is the root code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import Test from './static/chennasandhiram.json';
import AlbumDetail from './AlbumDetail';
import { Button, Spinner, Card } from './common';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';

console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Remote debugger'];

class AlbumList extends Component {

state = { albums: Test, loggedIn: null };

componentWillMount() {
firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: "xx",
      authDomain: "xx",
      databaseURL: "xx",
      projectId: "xx",
      storageBucket: "",
      messagingSenderId: "xx"
});

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
      } else {
        this.setState({ loggedIn: false });
      }
    });
    }

renderContent() {
    switch (this.state.loggedIn) {
      case true:
        return (
        <Card>
          <ScrollView>
            {this.renderAlbums()}
          </ScrollView> 
          <Button onPress={() => firebase.auth().signOut()}>
            Log Out
          </Button>
        </Card> 
        );
      case false:
      console.log(1234);
        return <LoginForm />;
      default:
        return <Spinner size="large" />;
    }
  }

renderAlbums() {
        return this.state.albums.map(album => 
            <AlbumDetail key={album.Block} album={album} />);
    }

render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.renderContent()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default AlbumList;
```

And the log-in form:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Card, CardSection, Input, Spinner } from './common';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  state = { email: '', password: '', error: '', loading: false };

  onButtonPress() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;

    this.setState({ error: '', loading: true });

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
      .catch(() => {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
          .catch(this.onLoginFail.bind(this));
      });
  }

  onLoginFail() {
    this.setState({ error: 'Authentication Failed', loading: false });
  }

  onLoginSuccess() {
    this.setState({
      email: '',
      password: '',
      loading: false,
      error: ''
    });
  }

  renderButton() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <Spinner size="small" />;
    }

    return (
      <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
        Log in
      </Button>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Card>
        <CardSection>
          <Input
            placeholder="user@gmail.com"
            label="Email"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
          />
        </CardSection>

        <CardSection>
          <Input
            secureTextEntry
            placeholder="password"
            label="Password"
            value={this.state.password}
            onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
          />
        </CardSection>

        <Text style={styles.errorTextStyle}>
          {this.state.error}
        </Text>

        <CardSection>
          {this.renderButton()}
        </CardSection>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  errorTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: 'red'
  }
};

export default LoginForm;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your code seems to be working.

Comment: Hi @vbandrade. Yes, you are right. Extremely weird behavior.
I just ran an update of npm and yarn. That seemed to have done the trick.